# D3 returns no JSON objects

Tags: javascript, websocket, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to read in JSON objects over a websocket for visualisation by the D3 library. I'm just checking if the browser receives the JSON correctly. This is the code:

```
 ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/dh");

      ws.onmessage = function(evt)
      {
        d3.json(
        JSON.parse(evt.data),
        function (jsondata) {

        console.log(jsondata);

        var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.Value; });
        console.log(data);

            });   
      }
```

But when I check the console log it gives me these errors:

```
[19:15:36.434] TypeError: jsondata is null @ http://localhost:8888/static/anEx.js:21
```

and console.log(data) is null.

What is incorrect here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`d3.json`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) is used to make HTTP requests that return JSON responses.

You already have the data in your WS message handler, there's no need to make another request. Just do:

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    console.log(jsondata);
    // handle data ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that and it gives me an error saying: [19:32:57.166] TypeError: jsondata.map is not a function @ http://localhost:8888/static/anEx.js:27

Comment: Yeah, that isn't a valid call on a JS object. Use [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) if you have underscore.js as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get the data through.